# Unable to display images images before uploading

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a menu that loads external file(form) in same page and for menu am using certain function for menu style

### Menu Function

```
function getXmlHttp() {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (ee) {
                    }
                }
                if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
                    return new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            }
            function hide(node) {
                node.style.display = 'none';
            }
            function func(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var q = getXmlHttp();
                var url = this.getAttribute('href');
                q.open('GET', url, false);
                q.send(null);
                var result = 'File ' + url + ' not found.';
                if (q.status === 200) {
                    result = q.responseText;
                }
                document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML = result;
                document.querySelector('#leftmenu').style.width = '70px';
                var items = document.querySelectorAll('li ul, #leftmenu b');
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    hide(items[i]);
                }
                this.removeEventListener('click', func(), false);
            }

            function slideUp(node) {
                node.setAttribute('class', "submenu hidden");
            }

            function slideDown(node) {
                node.setAttribute('class', "submenu visible");
            }

            function switchSubMenu() {
                var ch = this.children;
                for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                    if (ch[i].nodeName === 'UL') {
                        var v = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
                        if (v) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
                                if (v[j] !== ch[i]) {
                                    slideUp(v[j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ch[i].getAttribute('class') === "submenu hidden" ? slideDown(ch[i]) : slideUp(ch[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            var sm = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu');
            for (var i = 0; i < sm.length; i++) {
                slideUp(sm[i]);
                sm[i].parentNode.addEventListener("click", switchSubMenu, false);
            }
            var links = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
            var url = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
                links[j].addEventListener("click", func, false);
            }
```

And in external page(form) to display images in same page am using bellow function

### image preview function

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;}
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);};
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);}}
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

### ERROR

when i run **Form file** alone and add image, Images are display **but** when i use onload method opening external file in same page and add images i don't get image preview

CAN SOME ONE HELP ME WHATS WRONG GOING ON

Answer (score 0):

The way you use `removeEventListener` is not correct. The second parameter is the handler function indicator. Should be like this (without parentheses):

```
this.removeEventListener('click', func, false);
```

You should see error in browser devtool, I guess.

Comment: still i can't View images